# Why is this code keep being "terminated"?

Tags: java

I have this code in Eclipse:

```
package test;

import java.util.Scanner;

class test{
    public static void main(String args[]){
        Scanner Input = new Scanner(System.in);
        if (Input.equals("payday2")){
        System.out.println(Input);
        }
    }           
}
```

Now when I try to start the code/aplication, it terminates itself.

Any ideas why that happens?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You instantiate the `Scanner` as a variable named `Input` but never try to read.

Your condition

```
if (Input.equals("payday2")){
```

will only check if the Scanner object is equals to the string "payday2"  which will always be false, hence the program terminate.

If you want to read, you need to do `Input.nextLine()`.

I dont know about eclipse, but Netbeans would give a warning *"equals on incompatible type"* with this line.

Also, you should not name your variable with a capital letter as by convention, only class name should start with a capital.

So your fixed program would be

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
String value = input.nextLine();
if ("payday2".equals(value)) {
    System.out.println(value);
}
```

- Notice that I kept the string in a variable to display it as displaying `input` would call `toString` of the `Scanner` object which is probably not what you expected.
- Notice that I also compared the string in reverse order which is a good practice to avoid NPE even if not really needed here.

Comment: And if you knew how to make it work with minecraft, it would be great.

Comment: @TomLenc You're welcome. What you mean by *"make it work with minecraft"* ?

Comment: I'm making a mod for minecraft and I want to open my menu (GuiPAYDAY2Menu.class/.java) by typing payday or payday2 in the main menu..

Comment: @TomLenc I believe you should post an other questions with more informations relevant to this issue new issue.

Answer (score 1):

You never read input from the Scanner instance so the application doesnt block

```
String text = input.nextLine(); 
if ("payday2".equals(text)) {
  ...
```

Comment: String text = "payday";
if (text.equals("payday")) {

- Works for me

Comment: but then I have to type it twice.

Answer (score 0):

I think you mean to do:

```
String in = Input.nextLine();
if(in.equals("payday2"))
{
    System.out.println(in);
}
```

---

Note: in Java 7 you can do the following:

```
String in = Input.nextLine();
switch(in)
{
    case "payday2":
        System.out.println(in)
        break;
    case "payday the heist":
        //...
        break;
}
```

Which makes it much easier to manage different input cases.